# chmod+x command not found

Tags: chmod

I am installing PyRx software for virtual screening in Ubuntu 20.04 version but when I run the command:

```
chmod+x Pyrx-0.8-linux-x86_64-install
```

it gives an error:

> chmod+x: command not found

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Missing space in your command. `chmod +x`

Comment: chmod: cannot access 'Pyrx-*-linux-x86_64-install'.No such file or directory.. now this error is showing in terminal even pyrx folder is showing in downloads but couldn't get access. how I can get access to that directory or file from downloads?

Comment: you have to add full path to your command. `chmod +x /full/path/to/Pyrx-0.8-linux-x86_64-install`